# GAE Import of OAuth failing

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, yelp

I am trying to set up my first ever API connection with Yelp, I am using GAE on Python. To do so, I used the following example: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/python/search.py 
At first I simply try to run the code by the following definition in my app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /search
script: search.py
```

However when I load the page it gives the following error: *No module named oauth2*. I have read through many of the topics that seem to cover this error but none really helped in resolving it. I also tried importing oauth2client which was mentioned in some answers however this was also not accepted.

The only thing that was accepted by the system was

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth
```

Therefore I tried to work with this module, but immediately ran into another problem. I filled out my credentials (consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret) by defining them as default value in the parser definition. To replicate the examples request on https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python I also added a default value for 'term' (bars) and 'location' (sf).

When loading the page with this it however gives me the error *'module' object has no attribute 'Consumer'*, so this also doesn't seem to be the solution. As said this is my first time setting up such a system, so probably I am missing something obvious. Thanks a lot for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace modules just like that, the script you are referring to works with the [oauth2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/) library, which is different from [GAE OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview) (that's why you were getting the 'module' object has no attribute 'Consumer').

As explained in the [README](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python) of the yelp-api, first you need to install the oauth2 module. Note that you need to copy the installed module (or source) to your GAE project in order to upload it to GAE when deploying.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thanks for your answer. I am quite new to this and am not using a python interpreter yet - I just type the code in Sublime and see if it works by using the GAE SDK. In this case, how should I install the oauth2 library to my application? Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: In general you have to copy the installed folder (oauth2) or file (oauth2.py) to your GAE project. To find out where the installed package is just run the following python script: 
import oauth2
print oauth2.__file__

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. I guess I'll have to start figuring out how to use a command line on my system...

Comment: Found the package on the following website and installed it from there: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/